# Helluva Time Trying to Load XML in C# WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I am trying to do something super simple.  I just want to load a screen of fields with an XML file.  There will only ever be a single item with multiple nodes per XML.  It will always look like the below XML.

Fields are the same name but remove the "post" at the beginning so "postcity" has text that I am actually trying to load into city.Text

I have tried every tutorial out there but all of them center around importing multiple XML items like a database.  I just want to load this one.

```
<information xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<postRoomOrigin>OKC1234</postRoomOrigin>

<postcity>OKC</postcity>

<postchairCount>12</postchairCount>

<postfirstName>sdfghjqwertyhj</postfirstName>

<postlastName>erfghj</postlastName>

</information>
```

So here is my code

```
 private void clickLoadConfig_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("C:\\config.xml");


        //Now I want to load <postfirstName>Josh</postfirstName> into firstName.Text
        //So firstName.Text = "Josh"
    }
```

Comment: Please provide [a mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: private void clickLoadConfig_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("C:\\config.xml");


            //Now I want to load <postfirstName>Josh</postfirstName> into firstName.Text
            //So firstName.Text = "Josh"
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code will do what you are looking for. You haven't mentioned which type of fields you are using but you mentioned `city.Text` so I've just used a `TextBox` as an example. As Crowcoder pointed out in the comments, please try to provide enough code and information for us to be able to reproduce the problem you are having. If for example you are using the MVVM design pattern, my answer would need to use bind-able public properties instead of accessing the window's controls directly.

If you are new to programming, my example of MVVM may not mean anything to you but that's not important. I'm just pointing out that answers will change based on the information you give. Try to provide all of the basics E.g. "I'm using a standard WPF project. I have a Window containing 5 text boxes and I want to load the contents of an XML file into those boxes." Then provide the XAML code for your window, the C# code you're using to load the XML file etc. and explain the problem as you have. We ask for this as it makes it easier for us to help you and easier for anybody else with the same/similar problem to understand the question and solution. Here is the link which Crowcoder already provided to StackOverflow's guidance on posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

**Answer and Explanation**

To explain my answer, I have first found the root node from your XML file (i.e. the <information> node). The `SelectSingleNode()` method uses a query language called XPath to find the node you are looking for. The `/` I have used in `doc.SelectSingleNode("/information");` tells the method to select from the root node. You can find more XPath syntax examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

I then loop through each of the children in the root node, check if the child node's name begins with 'post' and remove it if it does. Finally I try to find a `TextBox` with a matching name and set its content to the value of the child node.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("config.xml");

XmlNode rootNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/information"); // Select the root <information> node

foreach (XmlNode childNode in rootNode.ChildNodes) // Loop through every child node within the root node
{
    string name = childNode.Name;

    if (name.StartsWith("post"))
    {
        name = name.Remove(0, 4); // Remove "post" from the beginning of the name
    }

    TextBox textBox = this.FindName(name) as TextBox; // Find the control on your window with the matching name
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.Text = childNode.Value;
    }
}
```

If you're using C# 7.0 or later (Visual Studio 2017 or later), the following:

```
TextBox textBox = this.FindName(name) as TextBox; // Find the control on your window with the matching name
if (textBox != null)
{
    textBox.Text = childNode.Value;
}
```

could be simplified as follows using pattern matching:

```
if (this.FindName(name) is TextBox textBox) // Find the control on your window with the matching name
{
    textBox.Text = value;
}
```

You can find more information on pattern matching using `is` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is